# C: pointer to array != pointer to &array[0]?

Tags: c, arrays

Suppose I have two arrays:

```
uint8_t buf1[10];
uint8_t buf2[20];
```

I now want to create an array of these arrays, e.g.,

```
uint8_t *buffers[] = {buf1, buf2};
```

When I look at the `buffers` variable in the debugger, however, I see that its two elements do not point to any elements of `buf1` and `buf2`, but look like random values (maybe the contents of `buf1`/`buf2`?).  Also, when dereferencing, e.g.,

```
uint8_t x = *(buffers[0] + 1);
```

the programs throws a bus error.

If I change the definition to

```
uint8_t *buffers[] = {&buf1[0], &buf2[0]};
```

everything is alright.

Why is there a difference?  I always thought that `array` and `&array[0]` are equivalent?!  What is the correct type of `buffers` to make definition 1 work?

**EDIT:** OK, I goofed up.  There is in fact no difference between definition 1 and 2.  I'm not really sure what change I did to see the correct values, but I do have a screenshot.

Anyway, I now know the answer to my question why the pointers are all bad, but you couldn't know because I stripped an important detail from the question.

I added `__attribute__((section(".foo")))` to the definition of `buffers`, and that segment `foo` is **uninitialized**.  Of course the values are random!

Sorry for wasting your time. :-)

Comment: I'm not sure about the issue. I tried the code on my side, and accessing buffers[x][y] was possible, which means it works (I didn't debug and look at the addresses though). However, I can tell you why your dereference test is wrong because buffers[0]+1 is just some random number, not an address.

Comment: @larsb: I guess they are equivalent and your first expression is fine. I run both under Visual Studio 2017 and 2008 to make sure. What compiler are you using?

Comment: Please show a full, shortest compilable code including all the `#include`s and `int main()` etc. that allows to reproduce the "bus error". Please specify the compiler and compiler options used and, if relevant, the target machine you are running this on. Please read [how do you ask a good question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and helpful to me [stackoverflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). I want to experience the same bus error on my computer too, what should I do?

Comment: `uint8_t *buffers[] = {buf1, buf2};` is equivalent to `uint8_t *buffers[] = {&buf1[0], &buf2[0]};`.

Comment: @EmmanuelO : On the contrary  `(buffers[0] + 1)` is equivalent to `&(buf1[1])`, so `*(buffers1[0] + 1)` is `buf1[1]`.  Of course that may or may not be what larsb intended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At [onlinegdb](https://onlinegdb.com/S1soiARjS) the following code:

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint8_t buf1[10];
uint8_t buf2[20];
uint8_t* buffers1[] = {buf1, buf2};
uint8_t* buffers2[] = {&buf1[0], &buf2[0]};

int main()
{
    uint8_t x1 = *(buffers1[0] + 1);
    uint8_t x2 = *(buffers2[0] + 1);

    return 0;
}
```

at the return statements has the following state:

[image]

Which seems to do what you expect, but not what you describe.  How does this test differ from yours?